# JavaFX ComboBox store selected item in csv file

Tags: javafx, combobox

so I am using JavFX to create a form that stores all the answers in a csv file. I need to create a dropdown menu that allows the users to select an option, which is then recorded in the csv file. I have tried a lot of different options, however I think comboBox is the best option.

I have no problem creating the ComboBox, I only run into problems when it comes to the method to get the value of the box.

Can someone help me find a solution, or suggest what another JavaFX menu I can use?

**This is the code I have right now:**

```
public VBox setFamiliar(){
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setOnAction(e -> toString());
        familiarComboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        familiarVBox = new VBox();

        familiarComboBox.getItems().addAll("Irmão", "Irmã", "Avó", "Avô", "Tio", "Tia", "Pai", "Mãe");

        familiarVBox.getChildren().add(familiarComboBox);
        familiarVBox.getChildren().add(button);
        
        return familiarVBox;
    }
```

**Here I set the ComboBox, this part doesnt seem to have a problem because it appears and I can select an item. I created a separate void toString() method that sets the value of a variable to the current selected item**

```
public void toString(ActionEvent e){
        familiar = familiarComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
    }
```

**The problem is then in the get method to get the value that was selected.**

```
public String getIrmao(){
        if(familiar.equals("Irmão")){
            return "2";
        }
    return "0";
```

I also tried to do familiarComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(), and other variations of this combination.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement -- that when a user makes a choice from the "Familiar" combo box, a value should be written immediately to a CSV file -- you don't need the `getIrmao()` method. You simply write the value out in the action which you are calling `toString(...)` (not a good choice of names), but which we will rename to `handleFamiliarChange(...)`.

Now the method becomes

```
public void handleFamiliarChange(ActionEvent e){
    final String familiar = 
        familiarComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();

    FileUtils.writeToCsvFile(familiar.equals("Irmão") ? 2 : 0);
}
```

where `FileUtils.writeToCsvFile(...)` is a method that does the file writing. Note that `FileUtils` is a class you have created to separate out file handling concerns -- your JavaFX view class should only concern itself with views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know I have the Csv file part in another class since it is a pretty big form. But this way it doesnt account for the several other options. Also isnt that essentially what I am already doing? I already turned the variable familiar to a String and then I do the equals, which is in a separate method so that I can the call it from the class that writtes in the csv file - it needs to be separate because the file needs to account for when the person did not select that option.

Comment: What does _But this way it doesn't account for the several other options_ mean? Do you want to associate a different numerical value with every item in the combobox's list? Also, you asked: _ isnt that essentially what I am already doing?_ Your code snippets don't show you writing to a file in the action method which is attached to the button. I'm assuming that the button (which has no text) is the submit button. When pressed, the action performed would be to get the value from the combo box, transform it into a int value, and write that to the CSV file.  If that's not what that button does...

Comment: ... then please provide a more complete, minimal example of what you are trying to do.